# UML and iOS Frameworks

Tags: frameworks, uml

What is the most correct way to express a iOS framework in UML? Package diagram or component diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the context - what do you want to depict. Package diagrams have a special stereotype for frameworks - `<<framework>>`, packages can be hierarchically composed, imported, contain other classifiers and they can be merged, where as in component diagrams you can depict different kinds of realtionships between components - requires and provides, which is interesting for the dependency analysis, and components are instantiable. There are many differences, as said, it depends on your intent.